How to configure `appscript.json` for a Google Sheets Editor Add-On?
I've been trying to submit a google sheets editor add on to the google workspace marketplace for the last few weeks, and have been stymied by feedback from the review team that my app is configured as a "Workspace Add-On" while it has the behavior of an "Editor Add-On". Note that it is supposed to be the latter, and I can't, for the life of me, figure out why its being classified as the prior. My best guess is that it is due to my appscript.json configuration, but maybe I'm mistaken and it's something else.
If it is the appscript.json file, could anyone guide me towards how that is supposed to look for a sheets editor add-on? Current file below:
{
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"
  ],
  "urlFetchWhitelist": [
     "https://example.com"
  ]
}


@Wicket I have indeed read the page you linked, along with all other editor add-ons documentation I could find. However, while there is documentation explaining the proper structure for appstript.json files for Workspace Add-Ons, the same documentation does not exist for editor add-ons, hence me asking in a somewhat open-ended way if this issue could be due to a misconfiguration in this file (which I then included) or something else.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78984293/how-to-show-instruction-with-image-after-install-google-workspace-extension/79056197#comment139425652_79056197

Allen N: That might be because creating an Editor add-on is possible without touching the manifest file. You should explain to the Add-on reviewers why your Editor add-on requires urlFetchWhitelist. There are chances that you should make a post on the issue tracker explaining your case.

Have you tried the steps provided by @TheMaster? It could be a setting that needs to be unchecked/turned off.

Thanks folks - I just went back to check and the toggle @TheMaster mentioned was checked, unchecking it and resubmitting to see if that solves the issue!

Can confirm that the step recommended by @TheMaster worked for me.
Specifically, navigating  google cloud console-> enable APIs and service-> app configuration -> App integrations -> uncheck Google workspace add-on.
Thanks!
